# how to test hazelcast Eviction in 3.9.3 Eviction not working

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am using hazelcast 3.9.3 version. Hazelcast Client and server as springboot application with single node server and single node client.

Configuration:

```
MapConfig h = new MapConfig();       
h.setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LFU);
h.setTimeToLiveSeconds(Integer.parseInt("60"));
h.setMaxIdleSeconds(Integer.parseInt("60"));  
h.setMaxSizeConfig(new MaxSizeConfig(Integer.parseInt(9000), MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.PER_NODE));
config.getMapConfigs().put("hsr",hsrMap);
```

1. Default partition is 271 as per documentation.how many items in  each partition can hold.
2. How to reduce and test the partition count from 271.
3. how to check the cache eviction work with above example?
   Map holds the value more than 9000 entries, eviction not triggered.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

1. If the number of instances in your map is N, then instances per partition would be N/271.
2. You can pass this in as a java arg or set programmatically as follows:

   Config config = new Config();
   //yes, this is vm level ...
   config.setProperty("hazelcast.map.partition.count", "271");
3. As per your configuration for map named "hsr", timeToLiveSeconds is set 60 and maxIdleSeconds is 60.  Eviction will kick in every minute and those instances sitting idle for over 60 seconds are eligible for eviction.  Keep in mind that evictionPercentage defaults to 25, therefore, every time eviction is performed, only ~25% of your node's count will be evicted until map size is 0.